# Laravel and React authentication setup

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I apologize if this might not be the correct platform to ask this question.

I need to start a new project. Laravel backend, ReactJS frontend.

Im really struggling to find out which authentication system to use.

I did read that a good approach might be setting up Laravel Fortify as a back-end and using Laravel Sanctum as part of the front-end to facilitate CSRF tokens.

Do you know of any good tutorials or where I can find documentation on how to use it in this kind of combination?

PS - I will move the question if it is not the correct place for it.

Comment: I don't know there is a correct place for this question to be honest as it's really subjective. This really depends on your specific use case, is your front-end and back-end on different origins (i.e. different protocol, domain name or port)? If they are then foritify and sanctum using api tokens would work, but if both are on the same origin then a simple sanctum SPA authentication would probably be fine. Of course you don't need to use any of that since Laravel does have some very basic support for this out of the box (you just need to know where to find it)

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos.  I just want to start of correct. Thanks for the insight. I suppose Sanctum and Fortify can be used in both instances of front-end, back-end domain locations. But might be a little overkill if its on the same domain?

Here is a link to some usefull info ( By the looks of it )
https://reactjsexample.com/easily-hook-up-your-react-app-to-laravel-sanctum-and-laravel-fortify/

Comment: You can always use the stuff that Laravel comes with but that means implementing things yourself and as I said there is no correct solution. It depends on how your specific site will work. If you want my suggestion, I'm always of the opinion of try to get something started and working while being aware of the libraries that are out there. In the process of developing you will figure out what features you actually need and start including those libraries. There might be a bit of cost of throwing away code but its lower than shoehorning things in where they aren't needed